# Alive Lisp extension 'alive:XXXX' not found in VSCode

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, vscode-extensions, asdf, quicklisp

Hi I have installed the Steel Bank Common Lisp(SBCL) and then installed Quicklisp and followed all the steps found here [here](https://github.com/nobody-famous/alive-lsp).

The quicklisp server runs fine but I cannot run any *Alive* commands from VSCode.
Whatever command I try to run I get the same error:

> command 'alive:WHATEVER' not found

Any ideas?

Comment: I've tried to quicklisp alive and start the alive server, but when I HTTP GET localhost:8006, I get an error : "[4/6/2023 16:00:39][ERROR] read-message: Unhandled header key: Cookie"

Comment: I installed it and it ran fine, maybe there is an inadequacy between versions of the Alive plugin and the Lisp version